# VirtualBox is not installing

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

[image: I am facing problem in installing Virtualbox in ubuntu 16.04 LTS]

I have tried all steps of reinstalling dkms: It was showing error -> Failed to request new MokSB state

Tried:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

But nothing happened...

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, you need to install the **DKMS** package first. So install it by typing:

`sudo apt-get install dkms`

I wouldn't advise that though. It's always better to download and install Virtualbox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

The instructions are very detailed and you can add their repo, so that it gets updated automatically whenever needed. The latest versions do not need DKMS, so if you decide to use Virtualbox repos, you don't have to install it at all.

Comment: Gently disagree: We've been using Vbox from the Ubuntu Repos for years and it works great. So if upstream version is better, consider adding a few phrases to explain why.

Comment: Sure. Ubuntu repos version: 5.0.40 having remained the same, since Ubuntu16.04 was released. Since then, the upstream version 5.1 was released, it received 15 updates and now version 5.2 is released having received two updates already. Both 5.1 and 5.2 releases have features that do not exist in the previous versions. It's not about weather the ubuntu repos version works ot not. Of course it works.